# Issues with Event Handlers not being removed (using RemoveHandler) when sender is part of another class

Tags: vb.net

I have a system where a Class of "Automation Providers" is working with some Control objects to provide some advanced monitoring functionality to them (by dynamically monitoring events).

A part of my code; A class called `Automation_Provider` contains a function called `Browser_Navigate` that takes in a reference to a `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` instance and performs a `.Navigate` operation with a URL.

The special functionality it provides is that it sets an Event Handler to the `Browser.DocumentCompleted` to perform some actions when the event is raised.

This part actually works. What doesn't work, is I'm trying to dynamically remove the handler that causes the Subroutine to be called in the first place, but it doesn't seem to remove the Handler and if I try to call the function again, it fires twice.

The code looks like this:

```
Public Class Automation_Functions
    Public Function Browser_Navigate(ByRef Browser As WebBrowser, ByVal Address As String) As Function_Status
        '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ' A bunch of URL checks are performed here to make sure the "Address" is a valid URL
        '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        AddHandler Browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf Browser_Navigation_Callback
        Browser.Navigate(Address)
    End Function

    Private Sub Browser_Navigation_Callback(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
        'Get the browser object from the sender and remove the handler that initially called this function
        Dim Browser As WebBrowser = CType(sender, WebBrowser)
        RemoveHandler Browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf Browser_Navigation_Callback

        '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ' A bunch of operations are performed here related to telling the caller of the original
        ' function about the performance of the web page - stuff like load time, etc.
        '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    End Sub
End Class
```

However the Past Handlers are never actually removed from the `Browser_Navigation_Callback` function - I know this because calling the `Browser_Navigate` function a second time results in `Browser_Navigation_Callback` function being called ***twice***, then if you call it a third time, it gets called ***Three times!***  - The Handlers just compound on top of each other since they never actually get removed.

I've been unable to find any reason as to why this is happening - I'm assuming it might have something to do with the fact that the `WebBrowser` object is actually inside of another class and casting the `sender` as a WebBrowser object doesn't refer it back to the original WebBrowser instance, but creates a new instance. However I have no idea on how to confirm that this is actually what is happening since I can't really see the attached event handlers in debug mode.

Other than that - this code should be working. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should be using `DirectCast` rather than `CType`, but I doubt that that would cause your issue. I also have to wonder why the `Browser` parameter is declared `ByRef`. Are you assigning anything to that parameter inside the `Browser_Navigate` method? If not, there's no reason for it to be declared `ByRef`. Again though, I don't think that that would be causing your issue. I can't see any specific reason for it in the code you posted. If you strip back your actual code to just what you posted, do you still see the same issue? What about in a new test project with just that functionality?

Comment: Stripping the code down to this doesn't change anything unfortunately. I've commented out everything except those lines that are adding and removing handlers and added a `MessageBox.Show()` to the Callback function but it was again called 2 times (showing two message boxes).

Comment: Make sure you have `Option Strict` on.  You can get nasty defects of this sort without option strict set when the handler signature doesn't exactly match the event, because VB will create an anonymous forwarding delegate (in both the `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler` call) and each instance of the anonymous delegate is distinct.

Comment: There isn't anything that stops this code from malfunctioning if you call Browser_Navigate() too often.  You could use a HashSet(Of WebBrowser) to prevent the event from getting added too often.

Answer (score 0):

One of the features of VB when `Option Strict` is not set is that it will use "relaxed delegate conversion". This means that when a delegate argument does not exactly match the required signature but is compatible with it, VB will automagically insert an anonymous wrapper that converts from the provided delegate to the required signature.

This has a negative interaction with `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler`.  VB creates a new anonymous wrapper on each call, and each instance is distinct.  As a practical matter, that means that it is impossible to remove a handler that has been added when relaxed delegate conversion is used.

With `Option Strict` on, relaxed delegate conversion is disabled, so it turns into a compiler error when the delegate argument does not exactly match the required signature.  I have not found an individual compiler switch that will turn off relaxed delegate conversion, so the only way to deal with this is to turn on `Option Strict` for the file.